# Skipping every M elements when iterating through an array in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda

I am new to Cuda programming and I have been trying to figure out how to convert the following code into Cuda code.

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i <= N; i += M) 
{
    output[i].x = signal[i].x;
    output[i].y = signal[i].y;
}
```

following a vector_add example, I was able to get this:

```cpp
__global__ void dec(const complex * signal, int N, int M, complex * output)
{

    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i <= N) 
    {
        output[i].x = signal[i].x;
        output[i].y = signal[i].y;
    }
```

And this is where I am stuck. In my understanding, all thread/units would calculate in parallel, so I wasn't sure where to inform the iterator to skip every M elements in Cuda.  An alternative I thought of was to check `i % M == 0`. But I'd like to see if there is anything else I should know first to tackle this problem, such as thread syncing and etc.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
__global__ void dec(const complex * signal, int N, int M, complex * output)
{

    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x; 
    i *= M;   // add this line
    if (i <= N) 
    {
        output[i].x = signal[i].x;
        output[i].y = signal[i].y;
    }
```

You should also make sure that you don't overflow the `int` variable.  This should be possible to manage by not launching unnecessary threads, i.e. don't launch a grid of significantly more than `N/M` threads.

Comment: Ah, this is a smart and easy way. A follow-up question, in the case where you do need to keep track of a shared variable, like `i` in this case or a sum variable (each thread is calculating a number and add that to the total sum), how would you go about that?

Comment: And by don't overflow, you mean not exceeding the maximum range of `int` after the multiplication? And by unnecessary threads, generally i do not want threads that are idle right, say if `N = 4, M = 2`, then I only need 2 threads to calculate, assigning anything more than 2 threads would be a waste of resources?